# Firebase Android- How to get value from another DatabaseReference inside a ValueEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get value from another DatabaseReference in another ValueEventListener. From the code below, there's an error saying it "Cannot resolve method 'getValue().'

I could make another Listener for mDatabaseUsers, but I need to get value for each child in mDatabaseEvents.

Could really use the help. Thanks!

```
mDatabaseEvents.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                  String userKey = dsp.getKey();
                  Log.d("TAG", userKey);
                  mDatabaseUsers.child(userKey).getValue();

                 }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from the `dataSnapshot` object not from the `mDatabaseUsers` object. There is no `getValue()` within [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) class.

You need to use:

```
dsp.child(userKey).getValue(String.class);
```

In case you value is a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child listener to listen every change under the root node.

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference(root_path_that_has_childs);

    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            switch (dataSnapshot.getKey()) {
                case "key_1":
                    break;
                case "key_2":
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Good luck

Emre

Answer (score 0):

I assume mDatabaseUsers is reference to the DB?  If not , get the reference before:

```
DatabaseReference <your reference> = <your DB>.getReference();
```

What you do here, is actually trying to change reference (add child) from inside the listener:

`mDatabaseUsers.child(userKey).getValue();`

It's incorrect, because you set the listener to specific DB reference. So add child to the ref before setting the listener, like this:

```
mDatabaseEvents.child(userKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for getting every child value separately.

```
dataSnapshot.child(userKey).getValue();
```

don't need to call with full reference. that's why u getting the error